# How does akka know which specific message reply is associated with the correct future?

Tags: akka, actor, future

Lets say I ask (?) the same actor for two responses.
It stores the sender for later.
Later, it gets messages back to go to the senders. We get the right sender (the one hashed to the message) but how does Akka know which message the response is for?
Is there something in the ActorRef that indicates which message each response is for?

Is it the 'channel'?

I'd like to understand the underlying technology better. 
I'll try to read the source at the same time but I think this is a really good question.

Code example:

```
class TestActor
[...]
def onReceive = {
case r: MessageToGoOut ⇒
      messageId += 1
      val requestId = clientConnectionId + messageId 
      senders += (requestId -> sender) //store sender for later
      anotherActor ! WrappedUpMessage(requestId, MessageOut))

case m: MessageToGoBackToSender ⇒
          val requestId = m.requestId
          senders.get(requestId) map { client ⇒
            client ! Response(m.message)
            senders -= requestId
          }
}


val futures = for(i <- 1 to 100) yield testActor ? new MessageToGoOut ("HEYO!" + i)
```

Now how does akka ensure the messages get back to the right actor??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `Actor` has a path.  From inside of the `Actor`, you could say:

```
context.path
```

From outside an `Actor`, if you had an `ActorRef`, you could just say:

```
ref.path
```

This path if the address of that individual actor instance, and it's how I believe the internal routing system routes messages to the mailboxes for actors instances.  When you are outside of an `Actor`, like you are when you are looping and sending messages in your example, when you use `ask` (the `?`), a temporary `Actor` instance is started up so that when the `Actor` that received the message needs to response, it has a path to respond to.  This is probably a bit of an oversimplification, and it might not be the level of detail that you are looking for, so I apologize if I missed the gist of your question.

Also, the `sender` var in an `Actor` is an `ActorRef`, thus it has a path so you can route back to it.

When a `Future` is created, akka creates a temporary (and addressable) `Actor` that is basically servicing that `Future`.  When that temporary `Actor` sends to another `Actor`, its `ActorRef` is transmitted as the sender.  When the receiving actor is processing that specific message, the sender `var` is set to the `ActorRef` for that temp actor, meaning that you have an address to respond to.  Even if you decide to hold on to that sender for later, you still have an address to send back to and eventually complete the `Future` that the temporary actor is servicing.  The point is, as long as you have an `ActorRef`, whether it's a request or a response, all it's doing is routing a message to the path for that `ActorRef`.

`Ask (?)` and `tell (!)` really aren't much different.  `Ask` is basically a `tell` where the sender is expecting the receiver to `tell` a message back to it.

Comment: Thanks - I do understand that - my question isn't how sender knows which actor the message is going to, it's which message specifically it is responding to. If I spawn off 100 futures, how does akka know which message the reply is for (or does it)

Comment: I changed the title of the question to better reflect my intention. Thanks again though!

Comment: I added a little more to my response.  Still not sure if it answers your question though...

Comment: Oh I see so the respond to path is not the actor but is keyed to the message? I'll look - thanks.

Comment: Great - thanks for your help. So the temporary actor is created on the /temp path. So each ask will have a different sender path that points toward the short lived actor. Thanks again!!